# Nil class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to display the related products  to a certain need, just the picture and the name nothing more depending on the categorie
here is mu controller

```
class RelatedneedsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @relatedneeds = RelatedNeed.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @relatedneeds }
    end
  end 

  def show
    s1 = '@need.category.name'
    s2 = '@relatedneed.category.name'

    if s1.eql?(s2)
      @relatedneed = relatedneed.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @need }
      end
    end
  end

  def get_name
      @relatedneed.name
  end
end
```

and this my model

```
class Relatedneed
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  mapping do
    indexes :name 
  end

  field :name, type: String

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and this is show.haml file

```
%h1
  %b= @need.name

#container{:style => "width:1000px"}
    #desc{:style => "height:400px;width:400px;float:left;"}
        =image_tag @relatedneed.photo.url(:normal)
```

this is my index.haml file

```
%h1= @relatedneed.get_name

#container{:style => "width:1000px"}
    #desc{:style => "background-color:#EEEEEE;height:400px;width:400px;float:left;"}
    = link_to "Check Need", new_need_path
```

I don't know if their is something missing and i get this error
NoMethodError in RelatedneedsController#index

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Your index.haml has `@relatedneed.get_name` but you have not set `@relatedneed` in your controller, only `@relatedneeds`. Is it as simple as that?

Also, your show method in the controller makes no sense to me. You have put your instance variables inside strings! You need to set your instance variables with a database query via the model first. Your get_name method looks like it belongs in a model as well rather than a controller.